# How to Convert this format mm/dd/yy to yyyy-mm-dd and add the hh:mm:ss in xslt

Tags: xslt

I wonder if someone can help. I've struglling to convert the date below. Is there a way to convert the date from mm/dd/yy to yyyy-mm-dd and add the hh:mm:ss in xslt?

here's my current input XML. I am trying to convert the "DateofService". The service date will always be mm/dd/yy without the hh:mm:ss.

```
                              <?xml version="1.0"?>
                             -<BCBSFMsg>
                               <BCBSFMsgHeader/>
                              -<BCBSFBody>
                               -<EIPMsg ImageType="PAPER"  MsgType="DocumentNotify">
                                       <ImageId>12344</ImageId>
                                       <FileExtension>TIF</FileExtension>
                                     <DateofService>11/27/18</DateofService>
                                                 <EIPMsg>
                                           </BCBSFMsg>
```

Currently, here's my query in the xslt:

```
<xsl:variable name="Date">
        <xsl:variable name="sqlXref"> 
          SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(19),ai.ADDLINFO_INDEX_15, 101) + '00:00:00' AS 'ServiceFromDate' FROM   ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION ai with (nolock)  INNER JOIN IMAGES_DETAIL id with (nolock) WHERE id.IMAGE_ID = &apos;<xsl:value-of select="$IMAGE_ID"/>&apos;
         </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="env:ExecuteScalar($provider, $connStr, $sqlXref)"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

I am passing the variable `$Date` in the element

```
<xsl:element name ="DateofService">
<xsl:value-of select="$Date"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: I have posted an answer that uses purely XSLT 1.0. There are more elegant solutions in XSLT 2.0. You should always add a tag to your XSLT questions indicating which version can you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an input XML that contains:

```
<DateofService>11/27/18</DateofService>
```

then a template:

```
<xsl:template match="DateofService">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>20</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(., '/'), '/')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-before(., '/'), '-00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-before(substring-after(., '/'), '/'), '-00')"/>
        <xsl:text> 00:00:00</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

will return:

```
<DateofService>2018-11-27 00:00:00</DateofService>
```

---

Note that this assumes all your dates are in the 21st century.